# ACF Repeater in Wordpress not showing images

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having trouble getting images shown with a repeater in Wordpress.
For some reason it only shows the alt text instead of the image itself?
[example](http://goedgevonden.net/elien)

the upper images are my thumbnail posts and are showing correctly.
Does anyone know whats causing this?

my code

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 left"><h1>COMMERCIAL</h1><br>
       <div class="page-header">

        <?php $mymovies = new WP_Query(array(
          'post_type' => 'my_movies'
          )); ?>

          <?php while($mymovies->have_posts()) : $mymovies->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="movie-colums">
             <div class="thumbtitle group">
                <div class="preview">
                   <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
                   <h1><?php the_title(); ?><br>
                      <?php the_field('year'); ?>   
                      <?php
                      // check if the repeater field has rows of data
                      if( have_rows('images_rep') ):
                        // loop through the rows of data
                        while ( have_rows('images_rep') ) : the_row();
                    // display a sub field value
                    the_sub_field('image');
                    endwhile;
                    else :
                       // no rows found
                        endif;
                    ?>                                  
                </h1>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP bit for the repeater stuff should be:

```
<?php if( have_rows('images_rep') ): ?>

    <?php while( have_rows('images_rep') ): the_row(); 
        $image = get_sub_field('image');
    ?>

        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>">

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

It looks like your example is outputting the image object so just wrap the image URL in an image tag.

Ref: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

Comment: @AlfredKwak check it now. I made some edits. Also update your first post with the full new code.

Comment: See my new update. Replace your repeater loop exactly with what I've done. You are including the entire image object, not just the URL.

Comment: Ha sorry! my mistake! It's working now! :)
Thanks for your time and effort!
Very much appreciated

Comment: Your welcome @AlfredKwak Please upvote and mark this answer as correct :)